# Dual cone of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $P\subset E$ be a cone.
 A nonempty subset P of a Banach space E is called a cone if
P is convex, closed, and satisfies the conditions:
(i) $λx\in P$ for all $x\in P$ and all real positive number $λ$.
(ii) $x,−x\in P$ imply $x = θ.$

Let P be a cone of a real Banach space E. 
The set $P=\left\{ψ \in E^{*} | ψ(x) ≥ 0, \forall x\in P\right\}$ is called the dual cone of P, where $E^{*}$ is the topological dual of $E$.

Let P = {x = (x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n) ∈ R^n | x_i ≥ 0, i = 1, 2, . . . , n}.
How can I show that $P^{*}=P$.

Comment: Hi! I think the title is misleading. You are not asking for the dual cone of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but of some special cone $P.$

Answer (score 1):

First, you can show that $P \subset P^*.$ This is straight forward, since for any $y \in P$ and $ x \in P$ the product
$$
\langle y, x  \rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_i \ge 0
$$
since all terms involved are positive.
On the other hand take a $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with one negative component, say $y_{i_0} < 0.$  Then you know that the basis vector $e_{i_0} \in P$ where $e_{i_0}$ has all entries zero but the $i_0-$th one, which is $1$.
Then you can see that 
$$
\langle y,e_{i_0} \rangle = y_{i_0} < 0
$$

So that $y$ cannot belong to $P^*.$ This proves that $P = P^*$, at least under the assumption of choosing two dual bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and it's dual.

Comment: Thank you for your helping.

Comment: @sbl if you think the answer answers your question and you are satisfied with it you should accept it :)